# UI Change in Global Navigation of SharePoint Online Modern Pages

Tags: office-365, spfx, modern-experience, global-navigation, modern-team-site

The Global navigation in SP Online classic team sites gets displayed next to the site logo and above logo in Modern Experience.

Its easy to modify CSS for classic pages as they are attached to a master page. 
But what could be done in Modern Experience, if I want to change CSS and bring the Global Nav to other location with improved font site? Refer below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: will need to use SPFx extensions, something like [global nav bar](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-tenant-global-navbar) and [inject css](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss). In Modern Pages, masterpages wont work, need to inject it via Application Customizer type SPFx extensions

Comment: @GautamSheth thanks, injecting css looks like a good idea. Just one thing we need to cautious. Since Modern UI keeps on updating, the class names applied on elements will remain for a really long time. As we can see in classic experience all IDs and Classes are predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom action which inject css, js or jQuery. There are many ways to do this. I am fan to do this with Office Dev PnP Powershell.